# My sidebar menu getting closed when clicking on sub items, need to keep open

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, bootstrap-4

I need to keep sidebar as open when i click on a subitems, now its getting closed. For example when I click on subitem manage competition, that event menu getting closed. Please suggest any solution if anyone knows how to solve it,please help me

```
<!-- Sidebar Menu -->
            <ul class="sidebar-menu">
                <li class="header">SECTION NAVIGATIONS</li>
              <li class="treeview">
                    <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-film"></i><span>Events </span> <i class="fa fa-angle-left pull-right"></i></a>
                    <ul class="treeview-menu"> 
                      
                   
               <li ><a  href="competitions.php" ><i class="fa fa-plus"></i>Manage Competitions</a></li>
                
              </ul>
                    </li>
                    
                      <li class="treeview">
                    <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-film"></i><span>Data </span> <i class="fa fa-angle-left pull-right"></i></a>
                    <ul class="treeview-menu"> 
                        <li><a  href="users.php"><i class="fa fa-plus"></i>Manage Users</a></li>
                        <li><a  href="cart.php"><i class="fa fa-plus"></i>Manage Cart</a></li>
                        <li><a  href="clients.php"><i class="fa fa-plus"></i>Manage Clients</a></li>
                        
                    </ul>
              
  </li>
                 <li class="treeview">
                    <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-film"></i><span>Settings </span> <i class="fa fa-angle-left pull-right"></i></a>
                    <ul class="treeview-menu"> 
                        <li><a  href="prices.php"><i class="fa fa-plus"></i>Manage Prices</a></li>`enter code here`
                        
                    </ul>
                </li>
                  
            </ul><!-- /.sidebar-menu -->
```

Comment: Probably related to the fact that this is some sort of "treeview", those are often implemented in such a way. But I can't tell what you are actually using for this functionality here, as far as I know, that is not a native BS4 component?

Comment: Given just the code provided, when you click on `Manage Competitions` your page *redirects* to `competitions.php` - ie you open a new page.  Your menu doesn't "close", the new page is rendered with it already closed.  Try updating `competitions.php` so that the side menu is already open on load.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you need to handle the closing via JS

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function () {
var treeviewMenus = document.querySelectorAll('.treeview');
treeviewMenus.forEach(function (menu) {
    menu.addEventListener('click', function (event) {
        // Check if the clicked element is a subitem
        if (event.target.closest('.treeview-menu')) {
            // Prevent automatic closing
            event.stopPropagation();
        } else {
            // Toggle the menu's open state
            this.classList.toggle('menu-open');
        }
    });
});
```

});
this should do it I think you will need to change it to fit your project :) not sure if you are using bootstrap core functionalities

Comment: I have tried it, but still its closing